# How can I use Message-ID in header to screen (filter) Emails?

Tags: email, spam, header, filtering

Recently started receiving torrent of spam emails immediately after ISP (Charter-Spectrum) switched to an upgraded Email system. Five of my ISP email addresses getting the same spam every day.  Some kind of UTF-8 coding is used to hide detection of text in the From and Subject lines but all have different (spoofed & hidden) From addresses.  The only thing consistent in all these 100+ emails is that they all have `@response.foxnews.com` in the Message-ID header line.

Is there any way I can filter-out these emails by screening-out all emails with `@response.foxnews.com` in the Message-ID header line using Outlook or using some interfacing email-spam-cleaner software?  Is there any email-spam-cleaner software that allows filtering based on any header line entry?  Is there some interfacing third-party email-spam-cleaner software that can do this? One that will interface with Outlook Express or with my ISP?

In this age of global spam epidemics why are the filtering and junk-mail screening option so limited that they are largely useless?

I use Outlook Express, which does not have as many options as the full Outlook product. Also, when I talk about email "headers", I am referring to FULL header lines. Most Email programs allow filtering of To, From, Subject header lines, but with the highly complex spam nowadays one needs to be able to filter ANY line in a full header, especially the "Message-ID" header line.

Comment: "why are the filtering and junk-mail screening option so limited that they are largely useless?" I think you have a misunderstanding. Email clients do have this capability (as shown below). Email clients written in 2001 and are years out of support  may have limited functionality. Switch email clients...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, most email clients support this capability. I use Thunderbird but Outlook can do it as well. I haven't touched Outlook in awhile, but it's something like this:

```
"File" tab in the main menu
    "Manage Rules and Alerts"
       "New Rule" 
           "Select a template" from the Rules Wizard dialog window.
```

Once you get into it, it should be pretty clear.

Yes you can filter on any header. I used to set a filter at work on a header of "PHISH" to flag corporate phishing test emails.

Answer (score 0):

I have another radical suggestion. These are not spam. Someone used your email addresses by mistake when they signed up for commenting on Fox News (hence the `@response.foxnews.com` in the [Message-ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message-ID) field). I would attempt to "unsubscribe".

Alternatively, you could contact your ISP support since it happened since a change was made on their side.